# Mysql - Merge two rows with values pairs

Tags: mysql, select, join

I'm definitely not a MySQL ninja, and I'm stuck in filtering and merging data in the same table.

Here's the table

```
user_id   |  profile_key  |  profile_value

2424      |  status       |  active
2424      |  channel      |  2345
3543      |  status       |  closed
3543      |  channel      |  2345 
...
```

I’d like to filter users with same channel value and AND only active rows

I tried

```
SELECT user_id, profile_key, profile_value
FROM my_table

WHERE (
        (profile_key = 'channel' AND profile_value = '"2345"')
        AND
        (profile_key = 'status' AND profile_value = 'active')
      )

GROUP BY user_id
```

It finds no rows.
I think I miss the JOIN rows part but I’m not sure how to implement it within the same table.
Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `or`, `group by`, and `having` clause:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(profile_key), GROUP_CONCAT(profile_value)
FROM my_table
WHERE (profile_key = 'channel' AND profile_value = '2345') OR
      (profile_key = 'status' AND profile_value = 'active')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT profile_key) = 2;
```

The `HAVING` clause ensures that you get two matches.  The `GROUP_CONCAT()` in the `SELECT` is because each row has multiple values (i.e. 2) for those fields.

I also don't think you need the double quotes around the numeric value, according to your sample data.

Comment: Great! I didn't know nothing about the HAVING clause!
The double quotes around the numeric value is because in the table is stored like that.
Thanks Gordon! :)